# Get Java instance from Flutter library

Tags: java, flutter, dart, webview

I'm using a WebView ( [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/) ) in my Flutter app for Android.

In my app, this WebView requires a call to [WebView#setWebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)).
We also need to pass a Java instance of the WebView to the Java library.
I need to get the Java WebView object from webview_flutter, is there any way to do this?

I know that the Java WebView is used internally (in webview_flutter) because I read the source code for webview_flutter.